# How to rotate image by less than one degree?

Tags: image-editing

1. How to rotate image by less than one degree?
2. Which free software can I use?

Comment: How to? Simply enter 0.5 (or what ever the angle you require) into the dialog. Which software? Most would have this feature I'd expect.

Comment: The most known free image manipulation software should suffice: GIMP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rotating with fractional degrees isn't something special. If a program doesn't allow it, it's probably a UI design choice of the developer.

[IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/), for example, supports fine rotation:

[image: rotate dialog]

IrfanView is freeware and it supports both automation (via command-line options) and batch processing.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are talking about an image I would suggest a rotation matrix. 
See here for an example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_%28mathematics%29#Two_dimensions
You can use arbitrary values as angle argument.

Comment: There's no indication in the question that the OP is coding a solution. Equally there's no indication that they're using some image processing software to do this either.